# Excel conditional formatting same cell with a wild card

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Hi I would like to search cell A1 for the letter B if the letter b is there then nothing else can be in the same cell and so the cell should change color. I cannot get this to work this is the formula i have.

=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)), A1<>"")

but this doesnt work

please help.

Comment: like "ab" doesn't change but "b" changes? Sorry, but to me it is not clear what you really want :(

Comment: if there is the letter b and anything else then it will flag it.

Comment: `=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)), LEN(A1)>1)` will do it here ;)

Comment: To complete @DirkReichel's answer, you'll then want to set up a Conditional Format that looks for this result and then just put a cell fill on it.  Perhaps `=If(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)), LEN(A1)=1),"Color","")`. Then conditional format when you find "Color" in a cell.

Comment: @BruceWayne `AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)), LEN(A1)=1)` would only be true if only exactly one "b" is in the cell... i think the `LEN(A1)=1` is a typo :D

Comment: @DirkReichel - "...if the letter b is there then nothing else can be in the same cell and so the cell should change color." Does that not mean he wants to color a cell that has "b" and *only* "b"?

Comment: His comment: *if there is the letter b **and** anything else then it will flag it.* if it is only b then he could use the "contain text" option or just `=LOWER(A1)="b"`... from how it looks to me: he wants to flag everything that contains b but not if it is only b. (But I'm not sure about text containing only multiple b's)

Answer (score 0):

`=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)), LEN(A1)>1)` will do it here ;)
still "BB" will also count... if you are only looking for "b" and something "DIFFERENT" then you need this:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"b",""))>0)
```

while it also can be written as:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1))*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"b",""))
```

When using it as formula for conditional formatting